# check all empty fields of a form using jquery

Tags: jquery

hi everyone i am new in jquery i want to place a check on my form when i submit a form a function just check all the fields of the form if any field is empty just show an error that please fill all fields
here is my code:

```js
function validate() {
  //get all inputs of the form in array
  var inputs = $('#form :input');
  var k = 0;
  inputs.each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      k = 1;
    }
  });
  if (k == 1) {
    alert('please fill all fields');
  } else {
    alert('submitted successfully');
  }
}

function postvalue(id) {
  $('#value').val(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Form Name</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" value="" id="value" />
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Double Button</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <button type="button" onclick="postvalue(1)">click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Select Basic</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control valid">
      <option value="">select option</option>
      <option value="2">Option one</option>
    </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Button (Double) -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Double Button</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="number" class="valid" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validate()" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: And what's the problem ?

Comment: always says please fill all fields even i filled all fields

Comment: Oh, I see. That's because `:input` select the hidden input, the buttons, everything, and all of those elements don't have a value, so it fails.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) { //on form submit event
  var emptyInputs = $(this).find("input, select") //find input and select as I see in your html
    .not('[type="hidden"]') //not hidden
    .filter(function() { //get all empty
      return $(this).val() == "";
    });
  if (emptyInputs.length) { //if any empty
    alert('please fill all fields'); //show message
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent post form
  }
});


function postvalue(id) {
  $('#value').val(id);
}
```

Here is working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Teo_van_kot/ygsL96zw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you don't want to submit the form if some inputs are empty

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from submitting

  var inputs = $('#form').find('input, select').not('[type="hidden"]');
  var k = 0;

  inputs.each(function() {
    console.log(this)
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      k = 1;
    }
  });
  
  if (k == 1) {
    alert('please fill all fields');
  } else {
    alert('submitted successfully');
    this.submit();  // submit form if valid
  }
});

$('#postValue').on('click', function() {
  $('#value').val('1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Form Name</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" value="" id="value" />
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Double Button</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <button type="button" id="postValue">click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Select Basic</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control valid">
      <option value="">select option</option>
      <option value="2">Option one</option>
    </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Button (Double) -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Double Button</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="number" class="valid" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Note that [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selects all input, textarea, select and button elements, and seeing as you have buttons whithout values, it will always fail.

Comment: yes i want that if fields are empty code shows error message